# Problems with data transmission in javafx and reuse variables

Tags: javafx, transmission

My program is structured package as follows
 -Browser.fxml 
 -Elements.fxml

+BrowserController : Browser transmit values url to Elements

```
@FXML
void txtURL(ActionEvent event) {
    Pane pnLoad = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Elements.fxml").openStream());
    FunctionController controller = (FunctionController) fxmlLoader.getController();
    controller.viewURL(txtURL.getText()); 
}
```

+ElementsController :,
  -With reading after I can only use the value url once for function viewURL

```
    @FXML
    public void viewURL(String url) {
        System.out.println(url);
    }
```

+How can I use the url again?

```
    @FXML
    void btnReviewUrl(ActionEvent event) {
      System.out.println(url);
    }
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Static variable in your class and assign the url value to that variable to ve used again anf across classes

```
 public static String urlValue;

@FXML
public void viewURL(String url) {
    System.out.println(url);
    urlValue =  url;
}
```

Comment: I had a headache for finding answers to my questions, guide your work thank you very much :D